# How to add splash screen to android app?

Tags: screen, splash-screen

I have developed an android app which has two packages in it.To which package should I add splash.java file and what changes should be done in Manifest file? PLEASEHELP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any one you can add. e.g package name is com.pkg to which it is added

Manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.pkg.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: Thank you could add the slash screen